# Display only single distinct id for multiple rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i've a table in which ID column contain muliple duplicate value, i want to display the ID only for the first row in mysql, please advise, please see the the below

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: That is a presentation issue. Don't do that in SQL. Do it in your program logic.

Comment: you have to do it somewhere like in excel, hierarchy in excel  can be very useful take care of these kind tasks, hierarchy only presents you single entry and their corresponding data set

Comment: This is a task for client's output subsystem, not for DBMS.

Comment: Which programming language you are using to fetch data from mysql? we can help you to implement this logic in that language. It will be solve if you implement this logic in program not on SQL.

Comment: Define'first'!!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you do this in your application.  However, you *can* accomplish this in SQL:

```
select (case when row_number() over (partition by id order by col1) = 1 then id end) as id
       col1, col2, col3
from t
order by t.id, t.col1;
```